# hide all the date before the selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am very new to jquery.  I made two jquery calendar. One is the departure and another one is the arrival calendar. When the user selects the date in first calendar ( departure ) , the next calendar should hide all the dates before departure date. Example : if the user selects Jan 13 in the departure calendar, the arrival calendar should automatically hide all the dates before Jan 13. How can I achieve this. My calendar code is below.

```
 jQuery("#datepickerarr").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            minDate:0,
            maxDate: '+3M',
            numberOfMonths:2,
            buttonText:"click here to expand the calendar"
        });
        jQuery("#datepickerdepone").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            minDate:0,
            maxDate: '+3M',
            numberOfMonths:2,

             buttonText:"click here to expand the calendar",

        });
```

Comment: You would need to set mindate of arrival datepicker on date selected event of departure datepicker using somthing like jQuery("#datepickerarr").datepicker().minDate: new Date(2015, 1, 13); where this date will be selected date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use minDate in your departure script on onClose departure date selection popup

```
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#datepickerarr" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}
```

See:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

on select of departure datepicker you can add:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                jQuery("#datepickerdepone").datepicker('option', "minDate", dateText); 
            }
```

[Here JSFiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/a3rza6xm/)

But you need to check another scenario where user change departure date